# MVC 4.5: Send an email with .pdf attachment using SmtpClient - what am I missing here?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sendmail, email-attachments, smtpclient

This shouldn't be that complicated.

I simply want to sent an email with a .pdf attachment.  The email sends and is received with the attachment, but it is < 1k in length all the time.  When I try to open it in Outlook, Adobe Reader gives me the message that it cannot open it because it is either "not a supported file type" or "the file was damaged (incorrectly decoded)".  Here is the code:

```
function Send() {
    var attachment = new Attachment(
    input.Data.ReceiptFile.InputStream, "Receipt.pdf", "application/octet-        stream"/*MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf*/);

    this.SendSubmitReceiptNotification(new Attachment[] { attachment });
    }

private void SendSubmitReceiptNotification(Attachment[] attachments = null)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     var submitForSamplesFromEmail = Config.GetSetting("SubmitForSamples:FromEmail");
                     var submitForSamplesToEmails = Config.GetSetting("SubmitForSamples:ToEmails");

                     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(submitForSamplesFromEmail) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(submitForSamplesToEmails))
                     {
                         // From/To missing.
                         return;
                     }

                     var toEmails = submitForSamplesToEmails.Split(
                         new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                     var to = toEmails.ToArray();
                     var from = submitForSamplesFromEmail;
                     var subject = "Test";
                     var body = "<strong>Hi There</strong>";
                     var isHtml = true;

                     //
                     // make the email object
                     MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

                     // set whether or not it's an html message
                     message.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;

                     // add the from address
                     message.From = new MailAddress(from);

                     // add the subject
                     message.Subject = subject;

                     // add the message body
                     message.Body = body;

                     // add the attachments
                     if (attachments != null && attachments.Length > 0)
                     {
                         // there are attachments that need attaching
                         foreach (Attachment att in attachments)
                         {
                             // add each attachemnt in order
                             message.Attachments.Add(att);
                         }
                     }

                     // add the list of who to send the email to
                     foreach (string address in to)
                     {
                         message.To.Add(address);
                     }
                     //
                     //message.HeadersEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode

                     SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

                     smtpClient.Send(message);

                     //Email.Send(to, from, subject, body, isHtml, attachments);
                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                     var error = e.Message;
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it ? maybe the attachment itself is no good.
Try reading file from file system and send it the same way .
I think the problem is in here "var attachment = new Attachment(
    input.Data.ReceiptFile.InputStream, "Receipt.pdf", "application/octet-        stream"/*MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf*/);"

Answer (score 0):

I reckon your input stream is pointing at the end, try to reset it with:

```
input.Data.ReceiptFile.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

Some streams do not support seeking, which can be annoying. In that case you need to copy into a temporary in memory stream, seek that to the beginning and then send the mail

Also the mimetype should be "application/pdf" [(source)](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm)